# No targets specified and no makefile found when compile OpenCV for WASM

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, webassembly

I am trying to compile OpenCV.js with my own additional bindings. I am following the instructions [found here](https://github.com/ucisysarch/opencvjs). However, when I run `python make.py` I run into the following issue:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "make.py", line 162, in 
>       emscripten.Building.make(['make', '-j4'])   File "/Users/antoinevandenheste/Downloads/webass/emscripten/tools/shared.py",
>   line 1718, in make
>       raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(cmd=args, returncode=res.returncode) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command
>   '['make', '-j4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Is there any other output first? It should say it was running cmake

Comment: I get a message like this `Stage 2: Making OpenCV`

Comment: if it isn't doing stage 1 of cmake then thats why it isn't working, looking at the source of make.py I can't see how that's possible

Comment: it's doing stage 1. It's in stage 2 that the error occurs

Comment: the first stage works perfectly. it's in stage 2 that this issue comes up.

Comment: Please post the full output, i.e. a [mre]. Has it actually generated make files in the build directory?